# Incorporating output from dataset into new row

Tags: r, dataframe

I was reviewing [Create a new column based on the the values and heading of another dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351298/create-a-new-column-based-on-the-the-values-and-heading-of-another-dataset) and [R - Add a column on a dataset based on values from another dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74403580/r-add-a-column-on-a-dataset-based-on-values-from-another-dataset) but I want to work with the output of a dataset, rather I have an output from one dataset that I am trying to then re-incorporate to my new dataset.

Dataset 1 to have row added

```
Species      Association Day   month  year  season  cover     evi
<fctr>       <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>
21  BW       RC           22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge
22  MANG     RC           22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge
23  RC       RC           22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge
24  RC        SKS         22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge
25  RC        NA          22    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge
26  SKS      MANG         22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge
27  RC        NA          30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge
28  SKS       NA          30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge
29  RC        NA          30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge
30  RC       BABO         30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge
```

I want to use the values after calculating the SES_C.Score or the co-occurrence of two species, calculated here from this `data2`

```
group_id                      RC  BW   SKS BABO  MANG
<chr>                        <dbl><dbl><dbl><dbl><dbl>
2-1-15-Deciduous.dry_470        1   0   0   0   0
2-1-15-Evergreen.dry_1850       0   1   0   0   0
2-1-15-Evergreen.dry_2020       1   1   0   0   0
2-1-23-Semi-Deciduous.dry_1000  0   0   1   0   0
2-1-23-Semi-Deciduous.dry_1310  0   0   1   0   0
2-1-23-Open.dry_1745            1   0   0   0   0
2-1-25-Evergreen.dry_1805       1   1   0   0   0
2-1-25-Evergreen.dry_2050       1   0   0   0   0
2-1-29-Mixed.dry_750            1   0   0   1   0
2-1-29-Evergreen.dry_1958       1   0   0   0   1

data2 <- data2[,2:6]
nperm <- 1000
outpath <- getwd()
Cscore <- ecospat.Cscore(data2, nperm, outpath, verbose = T)
```

When you run `Cscore` you get a table output with SES_C.score.

```
Sp1    Sp2    obs.C.score   exp.C.score  SES_Cscore    pval_less   pval_greater
<chr>  <chr>   <int>        <int>        <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>
RC  BW      5   5   -0.8079579  0.4845155   0.9520480
RC  SKS    14   6   1.5873256   1.0000000   0.2317682
RC  BABO    0   7   -1.0829308  0.4605395   1.0000000
RC  MANG    0   0   -1.1117101  0.4475524   1.0000000
BW  SKS     6   6   0.5844538   1.0000000   0.7442557
BW  BABO    3   3   0.3143282   1.0000000   0.9100899
BW  MANG    3   3   0.3914705   1.0000000   0.8671329
SKS BABO    2   2   0.2699785   1.0000000   0.9320679
SKS MANG    2   2   0.2804816   1.0000000   0.9270729
BABO MANG   1   1   0.1903501   1.0000000   0.9650350
```

I want to incorporate that value between species pairs into `data1` so output would be

```
Species      Association Day   month  year  season  cover     evi     Cscore
<fctr>       <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
21  BW       RC           22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge -0.8079579          
22  MANG     RC           22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge -1.1117101
23  RC       BW           22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge -0.8079579
24  RC        SKS         22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge 1.5873256
25  RC        NA          22    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge   NA
26  SKS      MANGA        22    1   2   dry       Evergreen edge 0.2804816
27  RC        NA          30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge    NA
28  SKS       NA          30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge    NA
29  RC        NA          30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge    NA
30  RC       BABO         30    1   2   dry       Mixed     edge -1.0829308
```

When I run `merge` as suggested, it works to an extent but doesn't read my table like I need it to. For example, the `Cscore` for `RC` as species and `BABO` as association is the same as `BABO` in species and `RC` in association.

data :

```
data1 <-  data.frame(
  Species = factor(
    c("BW", "MANG", "RC", "RC", "RC", "SKS", "RC", "SKS", "RC", "RC"),
    levels = c("BABO", "BW", "MANG", "RC", "SKS")
  ),
  Association = c("RC", "RC", "BW", "SKS", NA, "MANG", NA, NA, NA, "BABO"),
  Day = c(22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 30, 30, 30, 30),
  month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  year = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  season = c(
    "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry",
    "dry"
  ),
  cover = c(
    "Evergreen", "Evergreen", "Evergreen", "Evergreen", "Mixed",
    "Evergreen", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed"
  ),
  evi = c(
    "edge", "edge", "edge", "edge", "edge", "edge", "edge", "edge",
    "edge", "edge"
  ),
  row.names = 21:30
)

data2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group_id,                        ~RC, ~BW, ~SKS, ~BABO, ~MANG,
  "2-1-15-Deciduous.dry_470",       1,   0,   0,    0,     0,
  "2-1-15-Evergreen.dry_1850",      0,   1,   0,    0,     0,
  "2-1-15-Evergreen.dry_2020",      1,   1,   0,    0,     0,
  "2-1-23-Semi-Deciduous.dry_1000", 0,   0,   1,    0,     0,
  "2-1-23-Semi-Deciduous.dry_1310", 0,   0,   1,    0,     0,
  "2-1-23-Open.dry_1745",           1,   0,   0,    0,     0,
  "2-1-25-Evergreen.dry_1805",      1,   1,   0,    0,     0,
  "2-1-25-Evergreen.dry_2050",      1,   0,   0,    0,     0,
  "2-1-29-Mixed.dry_750",           1,   0,   0,    1,     0,
  "2-1-29-Evergreen.dry_1958",      1,   0,   0,    0,     1,
)
```

Comment: You can read in your scores text file with something like `my_scores <- read.table("Cscores.txt", header = TRUE)` if in your working directory, and then `merge` with something like `merge(data1, my_scores, by.x = c("Species", Association"), by.y = c("Sp1", "Sp2"), all.x = TRUE)` using the specific column names from the text file and your data frame. The `merge` will also add other columns for additional statistics...let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately, when I merge the two datasets as suggested, I get `NA` values for all of the `C.score` data

Comment: Would you be willing to edit your question and include the code you tried? When you read in your text file, use `dput` on that result as well? I just tried the merge and it seemed to work for me, though only RC/BABO, RC/BW, and RC/SKS had exact matches between the two...

Comment: I got it to work with your code with one last issue. Please see updates

Comment: The `C.score` data only has a single combination between RC, BW, SKS, BABO, MANG. Did you want to merge so that in `data1` both species BW and association RC and species RC and association BW receive the same score? In other words, did you want to merge independent of which is `Species` and which is `Association`? Based on clarifying this, I can update the answer accordingly. It might also help to illustrate what you final result should look like for some specific combinations. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I need to merge independent of which species is in the `Species` column. I have updated for clarity as well.

Comment: Please see edited answer below (bottom). Let me know if this provides the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in the scores from your text file with `read.table`. (This assumes your working directory is the same as used with the `outpath` argument.)

```
library(ecospat)

ecospat.Cscore(data2, nperm, outpath, verbose = T)

my_scores <- read.table("Cscores.txt", header = TRUE)
```

The `my_scores` data.frame should look like this, containing the C-score index values for species pairs:

```
    Sp1  Sp2 obs.C.score exp.C.score SES_Cscore pval_less pval_greater
1    RC   BW           5          12 -0.8021481 0.4775225    0.9470529
2    RC  SKS          14           0  1.5714268 1.0000000    0.2347652
3    RC BABO           0           7 -1.0340807 0.4835165    1.0000000
4    RC MANG           0           0 -1.0571308 0.4725275    1.0000000
5    BW  SKS           6           6  0.5403029 1.0000000    0.7712288
6    BW BABO           3           3  0.3620642 1.0000000    0.8841159
7    BW MANG           3           3  0.3162434 1.0000000    0.9090909
8   SKS BABO           2           2  0.2784037 1.0000000    0.9280719
9   SKS MANG           2           2  0.2678424 1.0000000    0.9330669
10 BABO MANG           1           1  0.1696401 1.0000000    0.9720280
```

Then, you can use `merge` back to your dataset, indicating which columns to `merge` on for each of the two data.frames. The `all.x` will keep all columns of the first data.frame `data1`.

```
merge(data1, my_scores, by.x = c("Species", "Association"), by.y = c("Sp1", "Sp2"), all.x = TRUE)
```

The end result is below. Only 3 pairs matched exactly (RC/BABO, RC/BW, and RC/SKS).

```
   Species Association Day month year season     cover  evi obs.C.score exp.C.score SES_Cscore pval_less pval_greater
1       BW          RC  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge          NA          NA         NA        NA           NA
2     MANG          RC  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge          NA          NA         NA        NA           NA
3       RC        BABO  30     1    2    dry     Mixed edge           0           7 -1.0340807 0.4835165    1.0000000
4       RC          BW  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge           5          12 -0.8021481 0.4775225    0.9470529
5       RC         SKS  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge          14           0  1.5714268 1.0000000    0.2347652
6       RC        <NA>  30     1    2    dry     Mixed edge          NA          NA         NA        NA           NA
7       RC        <NA>  22     1    2    dry     Mixed edge          NA          NA         NA        NA           NA
8       RC        <NA>  30     1    2    dry     Mixed edge          NA          NA         NA        NA           NA
9      SKS       MANGA  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge          NA          NA         NA        NA           NA
10     SKS        <NA>  30     1    2    dry     Mixed edge          NA          NA         NA        NA           NA
```

**Edit**: To merge based on species "pair" (either RC/BABO or BABO/RC), you can create a new column to define the pair (ordered alphabetically). Then, merge on the new "pair" column.

Note that `Species` was converted from factor to character to use in creating the new character `species_pair` column.

```
data1$Species <- as.character(data1$Species)
data1$species_pair <- with(data1, paste0(pmin(Species, Association, na.rm = T), pmax(Species, Association, na.rm = T)))
my_scores$species_pair <- with(my_scores, paste0(pmin(Sp1, Sp2), pmax(Sp1, Sp2)))

merge(data1, my_scores, by = "species_pair")
```

**Output**

```
  species_pair Species Association Day month year season     cover  evi Sp1  Sp2 obs.C.score exp.C.score SES_Cscore pval_less pval_greater
1       BABORC      RC        BABO  30     1    2    dry     Mixed edge  RC BABO           0           0 -1.0528984 0.4745255    1.0000000
2         BWRC      RC          BW  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge  RC   BW           5          12 -0.7665897 0.4875125    0.9380619
3         BWRC      BW          RC  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge  RC   BW           5          12 -0.7665897 0.4875125    0.9380619
4       MANGRC    MANG          RC  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge  RC MANG           0           7 -1.0382307 0.4815185    1.0000000
5      MANGSKS     SKS        MANG  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge SKS MANG           2           0  0.2721024 1.0000000    0.9310689
6        RCSKS      RC         SKS  22     1    2    dry Evergreen edge  RC  SKS          14          14  1.5631332 1.0000000    0.2387612
```

Comment: This works so far, however, why does the `SKS` and `MANGA` have an association with `NA` as all the values?

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree That happens because "MANGA" with an "A" at the end in `data1` is not the same as "MANG" in `my_scores` *without* the "A"...`data2` also has "MANG" as the column name, not "MANGA"...